# Javascript: How can I check if a fct is running and, if not, make it run?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script

I'm running a function in Google Apps Script and sometimes it times out and stop running. I would like to add something that checks (either continuously or once every x seconds) whether my function is running and, if not, start it. What would be the best solution for this?

Basically, I'm looking for something that does this:

```
if(!functionXIsRunning){run functionX}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var isRunning = false;
function functionX(){
  //Do something
  isRunning = false; //After function is finished, set isRunning to false.
}

function runFunctionX(){
  if(!isRunning){
    functionX();
    isRunning = !isRunning //Sets isRunning to it's opposite, that is true
  }
}

ScriptApp.newTrigger('runFunctionX')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5) //Change as necessary
  .create();
```

You might prefer to work with EventEmitters and stuff like this for avoiding `setInterval()` but this works just fine for basically everything.